# Detecting function object (functor) and lambda traits

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, functor, function-object

How can I detect the return type and parameter types of nullary and unary function pointers, std::function objects, and functors (including lambdas)?

Boost's [function_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html) and [functional traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/functional/function_traits.html) don't quite get me there out of the box, but I'm open to supplementing or replacing them.

I could do something like this:

```
namespace nsDetail
{
    class Dummy { Dummy(); };
}

template<class Fn> struct FnTraits;

template<class R>
struct FnTraits<R(*)()>
{
    typedef nsDetail::Dummy ParamType;
    typedef R               ReturnType;
    typedef R Signature();
};

template<class R, class P>
struct FnTraits<R(*)(P)>
{
    typedef P ParamType;
    typedef R ReturnType;
    typedef R Signature( P );
};

template<class R>
struct FnTraits< std::function<R()> >
{
    typedef nsDetail::Dummy ParamType;
    typedef R               ReturnType;
    typedef R Signature();
};

template<class R, class P>
struct FnTraits< std::function<R(P)> >
{
    typedef P ParamType;
    typedef R ReturnType;
    typedef R Signature( P );
};
```

But how should I specialize for functors/lambdas?

*Update:* Perhaps something like in [this answer to a different question](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/functional/function_traits.html), but translated from overloading to specialization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible in the general case for functors, i.e. class types using `operator()`. This includes lambda objects, too. Consider a case where `operator()` is overloaded:

```
struct functor {
    double
    operator()(double) const;

    int
    operator()(int) const;
};

typedef function_traits<functor>::result_type result_type;
```

What should `result_type` be?

Note that, as a workaround, some protocols (e.g. `boost::apply_visitor` from Boost.Variant) require that a `result_type` be present in the class, with the assumption that all overloads, while accepting different types, all return a type compatible with this `result_type`.

And of course given some types `T0 ... Tn`, `std::result_of<functor(T0, ..., Tn)>::type` gives the return type associated to the parameter types.

---

In the case where exactly one overload of `operator()` is present[1], you can take the `operator()` member and inspect that.

```
struct not_overloaded {
    double
    operator()(double) const;
};

template<typename T>
struct functor_traits {
    typedef decltype(&T::operator()) type;
};
```

`functor_traits<not_overloaded>::type` has type `double (not_overloaded::*)(double) const` here, and with just a bit of effort you can extract from this what you want. (e.g. a specialization of the form `Ret (T::*)(Args...) const` will match that type.)

[1]: but a functor can provide functionality by implicitly converting to a function pointer/reference, too, so you could miss that

Comment: What about something like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170201/c0x-overloading-on-lambda-arity/4196447#4196447 It's using overloading, but maybe something similar could work for specialization?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `std::result_of`?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Uniform_method_for_computing_the_return_type_of_function_objects

Comment: I also need parameter types and the signature.