# Understanding how the function traits template works. In particular, what is the deal with the pointer to member function

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am trying to understand [this code](https://github.com/aminroosta/sqlite_modern_cpp/blob/master/hdr/sqlite_modern_cpp/utility/function_traits.h) and I have found [some more SO content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765/340947) on this topic.

In compact form:

```
#include <tuple>
namespace sqlite {
    namespace utility {
        template<typename> struct function_traits;

        template <typename Function>
        struct function_traits : public function_traits<
            decltype(&Function::operator())
        > {  };

        template <
            typename    ClassType,
            typename    ReturnType,
            typename... Arguments
        >
        struct function_traits<
            ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Arguments...) const
        > {
            typedef ReturnType result_type;

            template <std::size_t Index>
            using argument = typename std::tuple_element<
                Index,
                std::tuple<Arguments...>
            >::type;

            static const std::size_t arity = sizeof...(Arguments);

        };
    }
}
```

This led me to learn about the pointer-to-member-function feature of the language, and it's pretty clear to me at this point *how* to use the function traits (it's fairly straightforward that I can pull out not only the return type but the arity and even the types of the arguments) but I have gotten stuck in understanding *why* this works, or indeed why it is even possible for it to work...

Comment: What specifically do you not understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's break everything down piece by piece.

```
template<typename> struct function_traits;
```

That is the primary template declaration, declaring a template class with a single template parameter.

```
template <typename Function>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<
    decltype(&Function::operator())
> {  };
```

That is essentially a forwarding trait to allow functors (objects which have an `operator()`) to be used with this traits class. It's a definition of the primary template which inherits from the traits for `operator()`. This version will be selected when the specialization which is defined later is not matched.

```
template <
    typename    ClassType,
    typename    ReturnType,
    typename... Arguments
>
struct function_traits<
    ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Arguments...) const
>
```

That begins the definition of a partial specialization of `function_traits` for pointers to member functions. When you pass a member function pointer type as the template argument to `function_traits`, this specialization will be selected. The return type, class type and argument types will be deduced as template parameters.

```
    typedef ReturnType result_type;
```

That is a simple `typedef` which aliases the deduced `ReturnType` template parameter to `result_type`.

```
    template <std::size_t Index>
    using argument = typename std::tuple_element<
        Index,
        std::tuple<Arguments...>
    >::type;
```

That is what is called an *alias template*. When you provide an index such as `function_traits<myFunc>::template argument<2>`, it will collapse down to `typename std::tuple_element<2, std::tuple<Arguments...>>::type`. The goal of that is to extract the type of the argument at index `Index`. Rather than writing out all the template metaprogramming code to do that manually, the author chose  to use the existing code in `std::tuple`. `std::tuple_element` extracts the type of the *n*th element of a tuple.

```
   static const std::size_t arity = sizeof...(Arguments);
```

`sizeof...` is used to get the size of a variadic template parameter pack, so this line stores the number of arguments for the function in the static integral member `arity`.

Answer (score 1):

@tartanllama 's answer actually forgets to add `std::remove_reference` from the code example, which is necessary to cover all cases.

The template general case that handles lambdas should really be:

```cpp
template <typename Function>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<
    decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<Function>::operator())
> {  };
```

If you're looking for a complete solution for all types in c++ that can be invoked, see [my answer on a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72693392/5082708).

Answer (score 0):

I did realize that the part including `ClassType::*` is meant to bind to `decltype(&Function::operator())`. I was learning about this construct (pointer to member function), but really having a tough time understanding why it's important for it to exist.

`ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Arguments...) const` is a template typename, in this case it is to be matched to a pointer to member function, and it is cleverly constructed in such a way as to be bound to the `operator()` member function, allowing the pattern matching to pull out the relevant types for us, those of the args and the return type. The `ClassType` would presumably become recognized as the same thing as the `Function` template parameter.

I was also confused by why a funny-looking templated `using` statement is required to look up the argument type values. I then realized that the `Arguments...` is a variadic template type construct which has to be tuple-ized using compile-time features and the whole business has nothing to do with "real" tuples. When I looked up `tuple_element` indeed it is intended as a tool for manipulating types at compile-time.

**the remainder of this answer I am not sure about**

I do wonder why pointer-to-member-function was used. I guess the reason could be that a regular function pointer or some such construct cannot actually be used to match the `operator ()` member of functors, as a member function requires an instance of the object in order to become callable. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6202320/340947) sheds some more light on this subject. I mostly understand it now I think.