# C++ Lambda does not have operator()

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, functional-programming, c++14

I need a method of figuring out a function's argument types, and so I wrote a closure_traits class, given below, as inspired by [Is it possible to figure out the parameter type and return type of a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda).

However, when I try to apply it to a simple lambda, I get the error that 'operator()' is not a member of '(lambda type)'. 
However, according to cppreference, lambda's do have an operator(). 
I also tried using std::function, and got the equivalent error.
I guess I'm not sure what's going wrong, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<type_traits> 
#include<tuple>                                                                           
#include<utility> 
#include<iostream>                                                                                                     

/* For generic types use the type signature of their operator() */                                                     
template <typename T>                                                                                      
struct closure_traits : public
                        closure_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};                                        

/* Otherwise, we do a template match on a function type. */
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, 
          typename... ArgTypes>                                                  
struct closure_traits<ReturnType (ClassType::*) (ArgTypes... args)>                                                  
{
    using arity = std::integral_constant<std::size_t,
                                         sizeof...(ArgTypes)>;                                              
    using Ret = ReturnType;                                  

    /* The argument types will be the same as the types of the 
     * elements of a tuple composed of them. 
     */                                                                                             
    template <std::size_t I>       
    struct Args {        
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<I, 
                                       std::tuple<ArgTypes...>>::type;                                                                                                                     
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

int main() {                                                                                                                     
    auto thing = [=] (int x) {return x;}; 

    std::cerr << "The number of arguments is " 
              << closure_traits<decltype(thing)>::arity << std::endl;                                                                                                                     

    return 0;                                                                                                                       
}
```

The compiler error messages that I get are below. 
My compile command is simply g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp.

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct closure_traits<int (main()::<lambda(int)>::*)(int) const>’:
main.cpp:9:8:   required from ‘struct closure_traits<main()::<lambda(int)> >’
main.cpp:34:82:   required from here
main.cpp:9:56: error: ‘operator()’ is not a member of ‘int (main()::<lambda(int)>::*)(int) const’
 struct closure_traits : public closure_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};                                        
                                                    ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:34:51: error: ‘arity’ is not a member of ‘closure_traits<main()::<lambda(int)> >’
 std::cerr << "The number of arguments is " << closure_traits<decltype(thing)>::arity << std::endl;
```

Comment: You do know why this is a bad idea in C++14, due to `auto` arguments on templates, right?  Asking "how many arguments of these types" is often a better idea.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I'm trying to deduce the number of arguments of the function and their types.  Why would that be affected by auto?

Comment: Your design fundamentally cannot support `[](auto x){std::cout << x << "\n";}`.  Callables in C++ do not have a fixed number of arguments nor do their arguments have fixed types.  It is like trying to determine the base of an `int` in C++: the concept does not really apply, as `int` doesn't *have* a base.  In your case, for *some* callables you can have fixed arity and argument types, which confuses the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your specialization does not match the `decltype(&T::operator())` argument.

Because of this, instead of choosing the specialization (as you wanted it to), the compiler is forced to recursively choose the same main template. Which makes it to apply `&T::operator()` expression again, after it was already applied once. I.e the initial attempt to do `&T::operator()` actually succeeds, but then the compiler attempts to apply `&T::operator()` again, when `T` is already `int (main()::<lambda(int)>::*)(int) const`. The latter, obviously, does not have `operator ()`, which is why you are getting this error message.

The reason it cannot choose your specialization is missing `const` in template parameter declaration. The lambda's `operator ()` is actually a `const` member of the lambda class. Add `const` to the declaration of your specialization

```
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, 
          typename... ArgTypes>                                                  
struct closure_traits<ReturnType (ClassType::*) (ArgTypes... args) const>   
...
```

an the compiler will follow the specialization path you intended it to follow.

And, of course, you have to print `closure_traits<decltype(thing)>::arity::value`, not just `closure_traits<decltype(thing)>::arity`.

Comment: I guess you mean the "specialization does *not* match"

Answer (score 4):

The compiler correctly gets the `operator()` of the lambda type, but a pointer to that member function does not match your specialization because of the `const` qualifier.

You should add a second specialization

```
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, 
          typename... ArgTypes>                                                  
struct closure_traits<ReturnType (ClassType::*) (ArgTypes... args) const>                                                  
{
    // ...
};
```

(Yes, writing templates to take a function type is painful.)

Comment: Writing templates that take a function is not painful: just use e.g. typename Callable and don't worry about all the rest. Same with typename Container.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone has trouble with this the correct code is as follows :

```
#include<type_traits> 
#include<tuple>                                                                           
#include<utility> 
#include<iostream>                                                                                                     

/* For generic types use the type signature of their operator() */                                                     
template <typename T>                                                                                      
struct closure_traits : public
                        closure_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};                                        

/* Otherwise, we do a template match on a function type. */
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, 
          typename... ArgTypes>                                                  
struct closure_traits<ReturnType (ClassType::*) (ArgTypes... args) const>                                                  
{
    using arity = std::integral_constant<std::size_t,
                                         sizeof...(ArgTypes)>;                                              
    using Ret = ReturnType;                                  

    /* The argument types will be the same as the types of the 
     * elements of a tuple composed of them. 
     */                                                                                             
    template <std::size_t I>       
    struct Args {        
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<I, 
                                       std::tuple<ArgTypes...>>::type;                                                                                                                     
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

int main() {                                                                                                                     
    auto thing = [=] (int x) {return x;}; 

    std::cerr << "The number of arguments is " 
              << closure_traits<decltype(thing)>::arity::value << std::endl;                                                                                                                     

    return 0;                                                                                                                       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: It has been (correctly) pointed out in the comments that this does not deal with `except` specifiers and certain cv-qualification cases. You might need to add those cases if you need them, or look at the link posted in the comments.

---

If you're looking for a (more) complete solution for all types in c++ that can be invoked, a lot of these answers work but miss some of the corner cases, like

- A reference to a lambda
- Functions and function pointers

Here's a complete solution to my knowledge (let me know in the comments if anything is missing):

```cpp
template <typename>
struct closure_traits;

template <typename FunctionT> // overloaded operator () (e.g. std::function)
struct closure_traits
    : closure_traits<decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<FunctionT>::operator())>
{
};

template <typename ReturnTypeT, typename... Args> // Free functions
struct closure_traits<ReturnTypeT(Args...)>
{
    using arguments = std::tuple<Args...>;

    static constexpr std::size_t arity = std::tuple_size<arguments>::value;

    template <std::size_t N>
    using argument_type = typename std::tuple_element<N, arguments>::type;

    using return_type = ReturnTypeT;
};

template <typename ReturnTypeT, typename... Args> // Function pointers
struct closure_traits<ReturnTypeT (*)(Args...)>
    : closure_traits<ReturnTypeT(Args...)>
{
};

// member functions
template <typename ReturnTypeT, typename ClassTypeT, typename... Args>
struct closure_traits<ReturnTypeT (ClassTypeT::*)(Args...)>
    : closure_traits<ReturnTypeT(Args...)>
{
    using class_type = ClassTypeT;
};

// const member functions (and lambda's operator() gets redirected here)
template <typename ReturnTypeT, typename ClassTypeT, typename... Args>
struct closure_traits<ReturnTypeT (ClassTypeT::*)(Args...) const>
    : closure_traits<ReturnTypeT (ClassTypeT::*)(Args...)>
{
};
```

Disclaimer: the `std::remove_reference` was inspired by [this code](https://github.com/aminroosta/sqlite_modern_cpp/blob/master/hdr/sqlite_modern_cpp/utility/function_traits.h).

Comment: It's a start and even covers many mainstream scenarios but still a ways to go yet. You're missing specializations for functions with exception specifiers (part of a function's type since C++17), cv-qualifiers on pointers (unless the caller explicitly removes them first via "std::remove_cv"), volatile specifier on non-static member functions, ref-qualifiers on non-static member functions, references to free functions (not supported in C++ for non-static member functions), variadic functions, calling conventions (not even part of standard C++ but part of a function's type anyway normally), etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it's too much work to properly tackle a question like this in a SO answer and few (reasonably) "complete" solutions exist anywhere in my experience so I wrote one (production grade, fully documented, free). See https://github.com/HexadigmAdmin/FunctionTraits (likely the most "complete" version on the web as near as I can tell at this writing and generally more complete than even Boost's own version at https://github.com/boostorg/callable_traits).