# Wrapping a function with c++

Tags: python, c++, templates, functional-programming, c++14

One of the nice features of Python is that you can use properties to wrap a function.
For example, you might need to apply a function to each of the arguments and returned values to convert them to something that your function can handle or the command calling it can handle.

How do you do this using c++ at compile time?
In other words, how do you define a function template wrap that takes two 
templated functors as types and a functor func, and then returns a lambda that is wrapped in the manner described above?

To try to make the idea a bit more concrete, we have the following. 
The idea here is to you have a function f that takes Args..., and returns ReturnVals... 
You want a function g that takes h1(Args).... and returns h2(ReturnVals)...

In other words, g = h2(f(h1(Args)...)....).

It is similar to [Python-like-C-decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679445/python-like-c-decorators). The difference is is it possible to do this entirely at compile time withou macros. That way it should be no overhead and type-safe. It makes sense that you should be able to do that because all of the relevent information is known to the compiler.

Comment: So you are wanting to call a python function from C++?

Comment: Pseudo code (ie. Python) example would be nice.

Comment: @ChrisBritt, no, I don't think so. The question is more like "here is a feature that Python has. Does C++ have this feature also?"

Comment: @Kevin Ah, misinterpretted it then. OP, Could you please update your question with an example of what you are wanting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python-like C++ decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679445/python-like-c-decorators)

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear.  Sorry if the initial question was not very clear.  Adding an example was a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out how to do this, and thought people on stack overflow might be interested in the method. The code is publicly available on a [Gitlab repository](http://gitlab.com/sangrey/Arma_Wrapper).

Sadly, it is rather complicated do in full generality, but the code below works.
First, include some metaprogramming headers and a type_trait to check if 
a type is a specialization of another type.

```
#include <type_traits>                                                                                             
#include <tuple>                                                                                                   
#include <utility>                                                                                                 
#include <functional>                                                                                              
#include "arma_wrapper.h"                                                                                          

/* Tests if U is a specialization of T */                                                                          
template<template<typename...> typename T, typename U>                                                             
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};                                                                  


template<template <typename ...> typename T, typename... Args>                                                     
struct is_specialization_of<T, T<Args...>> : std::true_type {};
```

We then define a closure_traits function that allows us to deduce the 
argument types and number of arguments of a function. 
I am thankful to the kind folks who answered my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411241/c-lambda-does-not-have-operator/40411400#40411400) regarding how to do this.

```
/* For generic types use the type signature of their operator() */                                                 
template <typename T>                                                                                              
struct closure_traits : 
    public closure_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};                                        


/*                                                                                                                 
 * This is adapted from the stack overflow question                                                                
 * Is it possible to figure out the parameter type and return type 
 * of a lambda.                                    
 */                                                                                                                
 template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, 
           typename... ArgTypes>                                           
 struct closure_traits<ReturnType (ClassType::*) (ArgTypes... args)   
                       const>                                          
{                                                                                                                  
    using arity = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 
                                         sizeof...(ArgTypes)>;                                        
    using Ret = ReturnType;                                                                                        

    template <std::size_t I>                                                                                       
    struct Args {                                                                                                  
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<I,   
                              std::tuple<ArgTypes...>>::type;                                

    };                                                                                                             

};                                                                                                                 


template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, 
          typename... ArgTypes>                                           
struct closure_traits<ReturnType (ClassType::*) (ArgTypes... args)>                                                
{                                                                                                                  
    using arity = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 
                                         sizeof...(ArgTypes)>;                                        
    using Ret = ReturnType;                                                                                        

   template <std::size_t I>                                                                                       
   struct Args {                                                                                                  
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<I,
                          std::tuple<ArgTypes...>>::type;                                

   };                                                                                                             

};
```

Now, I define to helper functions that allow you to apply a function to 
an unpacked tuple, (Just a version of std::apply from c++17), and 
foreach_in_tuple that allows you to apply a functor to each element in the 
a tuple. This is does in a recursive manner, which is why you need the helper functions.

```
namespace detail {                                                                                                 


 /*                                                                                                             
  * This function defines a generic lambda that takes can be applied  
  * to every one of the arguments in the  tuple. It requires that 
  * Func has a overload for operator() that can be applied to each of 
  * the parameters. Then it applies this lambda to each of the
  * parameters in the tuple.                                          
  */                                                                                                            
  template<typename Func, typename TupleType, std::size_t... I>                                                  
  decltype(auto) for_each_impl(TupleType&& tup, 
                               std::index_sequence<I...>) {                                     

        auto func_impl = [] (auto&& x) {                                                                           
            Func func;                                                                                             
            return func(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));                                                             
       };                                                                                                         

       return std::make_tuple(func_impl(std::get<I>
                              (std::forward<TupleType>(tup)))...);                           

 }                                                                                                              


 /* My version of c++17 apply_impl method. */                                                                   
 template<typename FuncType, typename TupleType, std::size_t... I>                                              
 decltype(auto) apply_impl(FuncType&& func, TupleType&& tup, 
                          std::index_sequence<I...>) {                       

    return func(std::get<I>(std::forward<TupleType>(tup))...);                                                 

}                                                                                                              

}
```

Now I define a function that takes its argument and wraps it in a tuple if it is not already one, but if it is it just leaves it the same. This is nice because then you can call wrap another function (f) with it and then assume that the wrapped function returns a tuple.

```
template<typename T>                                                                                               
auto idempotent_make_tuple(T&& arg)  ->     
    std::enable_if_t<is_specialization_of<std::tuple,T>::value, T&&> {         

    return arg;                                                                                                    

}                                                                                                                  


template<typename T>                                                                                               
auto idempotent_make_tuple(T&& arg)  -> 
    std::enable_if_t<! is_specialization_of<std::tuple, T>::value,             

       decltype(std::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(arg)))>  {                    

    return std::make_tuple(std::forward<T>(arg));                                                                  

}
```

These two functions are just a slightly less generic version of c++17
std::apply and a function that applies a functor to each element in a tuple.

```
template<typename FuncType, typename TupleType>                                                                    
decltype(auto) apply(FuncType&& func, TupleType&& tup) {                                                                                                                  
    return detail::apply_impl(std::forward<FuncType>(func), 
                               std::forward<TupleType>(tup),  
                             std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<
                             std::decay_t<TupleType>>::value>{});                

}                                                                                                                  



 /* Applies a Functor Func to each element of the tuple. As you might 
  * expect, the Functor needs overloads for all of the types that in 
  * the tuple or the code will not compile.                                            
  */                                                                                                                
 template<typename Func, typename TupleType>                                                                        
 decltype(auto) for_each_in_tuple(TupleType&& tup) {                                                                

     return  detail::for_each_impl<Func>(std::forward<TupleType>(tup),                                              

                             std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<
                             std::decay_t<TupleType>>::value>{});         

 }
```

The following function applies the function to each of the arguments by unpacking it using recursive methods. It's the same method used in the apply_imp and foreach_in_tupl_impl methods above. 
It also wraps the return values.

```
namespace detail {                                                                                                 

    /*                                                                                                             
     * This function takes a function and an index sequence with its 
     * number of arguments. It then figures out the types of its
     * arguments, and creates a new function with each of the 
     * arguments and each of the returned values converted to the 
     * new types.                                                                          
     */                                                                                                            
    template<typename ArgWrapper, typename ReturnWrapper, 
             typename FuncType, size_t...I>                           
    auto wrap_impl(FuncType&& func, std::index_sequence<I...>) {                                                   

        /* 
         * This is used to figure out what the argument types of 
         * func are 
         */                                       
        using traits = closure_traits<
                           typename std::decay_t<FuncType>>;                                            

        auto wrapped_func = [=] (std::result_of_t<ReturnWrapper(                                                   
            typename traits:: template Args<I>::type)>... args) {                                                  

            /* 
             * Apply the argument wrapper function to each of the
             * arguments of the new function. 
             */                
            decltype(auto) tup1 = for_each_in_tuple<ArgWrapper>
                    (std::forward_as_tuple(args...));                   
            /* Apply the old function to the wrapped arguments. */                                                 
            decltype(auto) tup2 = idempotent_make_tuple(apply(func,                                                
                std::forward<std::decay_t<decltype(tup1)>>(tup1)));                                                
            /* 
             * Apply the Return wrapper to the return value of the 
             * old function 
             */                                 
            decltype(auto) tup3 = for_each_in_tuple<ReturnWrapper>(                                                
                std::forward<std::decay_t<decltype(tup2)>>(tup2));                                                 

            return tup3;                                                                                           
        };                                                                                                         

        return wrapped_func;                                                                                       

    }                                                                                                              


}
```

The function that actually does the wrapping.

```
template<typename ArgWrapper, typename ReturnWrapper, 
         typename FuncType>                      
auto wrap(FuncType&& func) {                                                                                       

    return detail::wrap_impl<ArgWrapper, ReturnWrapper>(                                                           
               std::forward<FuncType>(func),
               std::make_index_sequence<closure_traits<
                       FuncType>::arity::value> {}); 
}
```