# How can solve vs2019 C++ template function trait problem?

Tags: c++, gcc

I found a solution on [Understanding how the function traits template works. In particular, what is the deal with the pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283919/understanding-how-the-function-traits-template-works-in-particular-what-is-the) to get type of function parameters types by using templates.  But following code gets "error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token '<', expected 'declaration'" on VS2019.  It works on GCC ?  When I use c++17 or c++20 gets same error.  This seems vs2019 bug ?

Any suggestions ?

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
    
class CChTest
{
    public:
        CChTest()
        {
        }

        bool    ChDeneme(int a, int b)
        {
            return false;
        }
};
    
template<typename> struct function_traits;

template <typename Function>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<
    decltype(&std::remove_reference<Function>::type::operator())>
{
};
    
template <
    typename    ClassType,
    typename    ReturnType,
    typename... Arguments>
struct function_traits<
    ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Arguments...) const>
    : function_traits<ReturnType(*)(Arguments...)>
{
};
    
template <
    typename    ClassType,
    typename    ReturnType,
    typename... Arguments>
struct function_traits<
    ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Arguments...)>
    : function_traits<ReturnType(*)(Arguments...)>
{
};

template <
    typename    ReturnType,
    typename... Arguments>
struct function_traits<
    ReturnType(*)(Arguments...)> 
{
    typedef ReturnType result_type;

    template <std::size_t Index>

    using argument = typename std::tuple_element<
        Index,
        std::tuple<Arguments...>>::type;

    static const std::size_t arity = sizeof...(Arguments);
};
    
template <
    typename    _ChClass,
    typename    _ChFunction>
void ChTemplate(
    _ChClass    cl,
    _ChFunction fn)
{
    typename function_traits<_ChFunction>::argument<0>  a;
}
    
int main()
{
    CChTest ChTest;

    ChTemplate(&ChTest, &CChTest::ChDeneme);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Paraphrasing errors has the problem of missing information, such as the line number where the error occurs. Please read about the importance of a proper [mre].

Comment: As somewhat of an aside, identifiers like `_ChClass` (leading underscore followed by a capital letter) are [reserved to the implementation for any use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/817643). To use one is asking for trouble. So I recommend fixing that for portability. And who knows... your problem may then get magically solved.

Comment: still same error.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I changed capital letters to lower letters on my codes.  So, I get same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `template` keyword to make `argument` a dependent template name:

```
template <
    typename    _ChClass,
    typename    _ChFunction>
void ChTemplate(
    _ChClass    cl,
    _ChFunction fn)
{
    typename function_traits<_ChFunction>::template argument<0>  a;
    //                                     ^^^^^^^^
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PEKsjqPae)