# How can I get the type of a function argument using type traits in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this function:

```
template <typename F>
void doSomethingWith(F func) {

   T obj = getObjectFromSomewhereElse<T>();
   func(obj);
}
```

I want to deduce the type `T` from `F`, where `T` is the first (and in this case, only) argument to `F`. Is there a way to do this in C++?

Comment: Found in [accept-any-kind-of-callable-and-also-know-argument-type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465394/accept-any-kind-of-callable-and-also-know-argument-type/21466644#comment32402978_21466644), http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00750bf7564ab6d4 may help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one simple way, for one argument:

```
template<typename> struct arg;

template<typename R, typename A>
struct arg<R(*)(A)> { using type = A; };
```

to be used as ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fee3729a5fa75068))

```
template<typename T>
T getObjectFromSomewhereElse() { return T{}; }

template <typename F>
void doSomethingWith(F func)
{
    using T = typename arg<F>::type;
    T obj = getObjectFromSomewhereElse<T>();
    func(obj);
}

void f(int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }

int main ()
{
    doSomethingWith(f);  // output 0
}
```

Here we know that `func` will decay to a pointer, that's why we define `arg` for a pointer to function.

This only works for functions. For function objects (and lambdas) we need to use a pointer to member `operator()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486468/2644390) (thanks Jarod42) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda) (thanks OmnipotentEntity).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at [Boost.FunctionTypes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/introduction.html). Alternatively, this can be done via template specialization, if you want to do it yourself. I.e. specialize a template for a function type with parameter type A and look at what that is:

```
template <class T> class parse_first_arg {};
template <class R, class A> class parse_first_arg<R(A)> {typedef A type;};
```