# QVariant's Visitor pattern (without manual type testing and casting)

Tags: c++, qt, visitor-pattern, qvariant

Does Qt's QVariant class has any existing (and convenient) Visitor pattern implementation?

If not, is it possible to achieve something similar to `boost::apply_visitor()`, i.e. minimize the the duplication in regard to testing the type and casting?

I want to achieve something along the following lines:

```c++
/* I have a QVariant that can contain anything, including user types */
QVariant variant;    

/* But in my Visitor I'm interested only in ints and QStrings (for the sake of the example) */
struct Visitor
{
   void operator()(int i) { /* do something with int */ } 
   void operator()(QString s) { /* ...or QString */ }
};

/* The question is: */
/* Can this be implemented in a generic way (without resorting to particular template parameters)? */
template <typename VisitorT>
void visit(QVariant variant, VisitorT visitor)
{
   if (variant.canConvert<int>()) {
      visitor(variant.value<int>());
   } else if (variant.canConvert<QString>()) {
      visitor(variant.value<QString>());
   } /* and so on (if needed for other types)... */
}

/* So that later I can use it like that */
visit(variant, Visitor());
```

Edit 1: `QVariant::canConvert<T>()` may not be the best solution above, but the point is: can the type mapping (between `QMetaType` and `typename T`) be achieved automatically?

Edit 2: "Visitor functor" or "Visitor function" doesn't really matter for me. What matters is I want to avoid testing the type and casting (if at all possible).

Comment: Small remark: I think that you need to do a map of typeid's. It will be faster than if-elseif pattern.

Comment: What kind of mapping do you have in mind? I.e. mapping between TypeId and 'what'?

Comment: I believe @DmitrySazonov is referring to [`QVariant::type()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#type).

Comment: Using `canConvert` will also run into trouble with integral types (e.g. a `double` converted to an `int`) and other built-in Qt type conversions (like `QRectF` to `QRect`)

Comment: @JonHarper Good point, it was working fine for my own types. All in all, I was looking for a generic solution that could even do it entirely different way. Now that I think of it, it may not be possible if the type is erased and only 'type id' is preserved.

Comment: When you register a metatype, it is given a unique value that you can check against. See here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#userType

Comment: @JonHarper OK, further thinking about it, if I can get the type T from the QMetaType, then I have everything I need to come up with a solution. But can I? E.g. if I have something like `T getType<QMetaType::Int>()`. Does something similar exist in Qt?

Comment: I'd suggest reading over the `QVariant` documentation, then coming back and reframing your question with more detail based on any insights you glean.

Comment: Are you trying to ask, essentially: "Is there a way for C++ to iterate, at compile time, the argument types of every overload of a method in a class, and generate some code for each type?" If so, then the answer is: no. That would require introspection. And that points you to a solution :)

Comment: @KubaOber The thing is that in case of a static dispatch, I probably wouldn't have to "iterate" over the overloads -- I'd just get a "compliation error" ;-) What motivated the question in the first place was `boost::variant` not having to iterate over anything in the `boost::apply_visitor()`. But now I get that in case of QVariant type is erased to a point, that one cannot statically "revive" it :-) Anyway, thanks!

Comment: `boost::apply_visitor` definitely does compile-time iteration over all the types in a `boost::variant`, and generates the code for each of the types. This can only be done when a class contains such information in a form accessible to the compiler. `boost::variant` does, `QVariant` doesn't because it can't: it can possibly carry any type, and is not limited to a known set of types.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that already :-) Thanks, though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Introspectable Visitor

You could leverage the introspection information generated by moc. Declare your visitor to be `Q_GADGET`. This adds a single static `staticMetaObject` member to the visitor, containing the information about the invokable methods there.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/variant-convert-38071414
#include <QtCore>

struct Foo {
   int a;
   Foo() = default;
   explicit Foo(int a) : a(a) {}
};
QDebug operator<<(QDebug debug, const Foo & f) {
   return debug << f.a;
}
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo)

struct Visitor
{
   Q_GADGET
   Q_INVOKABLE void visit(int i) { qDebug() << "got int" << i; }
   Q_INVOKABLE void visit(const QString & s) { qDebug() << "got string" << s; }
   Q_INVOKABLE void visit(const Foo & f) { qDebug() << "got foo" << f; }
};
```

Qt has all the information necessary to pass opaque types around as arguments to invokable methods:

```
template <typename V>
bool visit(const QVariant & variant, const V & visitor) {
   auto & metaObject = V::staticMetaObject;
   for (int i = 0; i < metaObject.methodCount(); ++i) {
      auto method = metaObject.method(i);
      if (method.parameterCount() != 1)
         continue;
      auto arg0Type = method.parameterType(0);
      if (variant.type() != (QVariant::Type)arg0Type)
         continue;
      QGenericArgument arg0{variant.typeName(), variant.constData()};
      if (method.invokeOnGadget((void*)&visitor, arg0))
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Perhaps this is then what you were after:

```
int main() {
   visit(QVariant{1}, Visitor{});
   visit(QVariant{QStringLiteral("foo")}, Visitor{});
   visit(QVariant::fromValue(Foo{10}), Visitor{});
}

#include "main.moc"
```

This concludes the example.

#### Non-Introspectable Visitor

You can factor out the conversion to a type and conditional code execution:

```
void visitor(const QVariant & val) {
   withConversion(val, [](int v){
      qDebug() << "got an int" << v;
   })
   || withConversion(val, [](const QString & s){
      qDebug() << "got a string" << s;
   });
}

int main() {
   visitor(QVariant{1});
   visitor(QVariant{QStringLiteral("foo")});
}
```

The `withConversion` function deduces the argument type of the callable and invokes the callable if the variant is of the matching type:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct func_traits : public func_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct func_traits<Ret(C::*)(Args...) const> {
   using result_type = Ret;
   template <std::size_t i>
   struct arg {
      using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
   };
};

template <typename F> bool withConversion(const QVariant & val, F && fun) {
   using traits = func_traits<typename std::decay<F>::type>;
   using arg0_t = typename std::decay<typename traits::template arg<0>::type>::type;
   if (val.type() == (QVariant::Type)qMetaTypeId<arg0_t>()) {
      fun(val.value<arg0_t>());
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21465394/1329652) for more about argument type deduction in callables.

Comment: Functor or function doesn't matter here. What matters is I want to avoid testing the type and then casting because it's repeating the same thing all over again.

Comment: I appreciate the elegance of your solution. This is also somewhat similar to what I came up with (ending up with `||` between functions checking if the type is matching).