# is it possible to passing a variable/function-return as a template argument

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qt5

Is it possible to pass a variable or a value returned by a function as a template argument.

Example:

```
QVariantHash options;
options.insert("fontStyle", fontStyleObject);  // QFont fontStyleObject
options.insert("fontColor", fontColorObject);  // QColor fontColorObject
Q_FOREACH(const QVariant &option, options){
    qDebug() << option.value<option.typeName()>();
}
```

As you saw, I have passed `option.typeName()` as a template argument and that method returns the type of the object as `QString`.

I have already done that but there is an error message: `error: C2974: 'QVariant::value': invalid template argument for 'T', type expected`.

**Is it possible to pass a variable or a value returned by a function as a template argument? and if not, what's the alternative way to do that?**

Comment: All template magic happens at compile-time. At compile-time, all types for all template instantiations must be known. If `option.typeName()` might be known at compile-time (for example, it's some dependent type of the QVariantHash instance, which I doubt), then you can. Otherwise, you can't.

Comment: Also, won't `qDebug() << option.toString()` work in your particular case? I mean, you are trying to serialize it anyway, right?

Comment: @iehrlich: Don't worry, this line `qDebug() << option.value<option.typeName()>();`, is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible if the template has a non-type template parameter and the function call is a constant expression. For example

```
#include <type_traits>

constexpr int foo() {
    return 42;
}

template <int x>
std::integral_constant<int, x> bar() { return {}; }

int main() {
    bar<foo()>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need that at all, you can just use

T QVariant::value() const

you can feed the resulting T to qDebug() operator <<. You might need to define how you print your T, have a look at: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdebug.html#writing-custom-types-to-a-stream

```
for ( auto const & option : options)
  qDebug() << option.value(); //returns T automatically
```

Comment: The problem not in `qDebug` or print out the value of objects, this line `qDebug() << option.value<option.typeName()>();` is just an example, but the real target is to retrieve each object to its original type.

Comment: then option.value() returns the original type, which is T

Comment: To use this method `T QVariant::value()` you must append the type of object which you expect as a template argument like this `value<type>()`, or an error message will appear.

Comment: You were right, take a look at this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071414/qvariants-visitor-pattern-without-manual-type-testing-and-casting